How to get list of active solana wallets
I am currently launching a token and want to airdrop it as a marketing tool, I couldn't find any tool which would help me find wallet besides solscan api which doesn't really help with thing besides the paid one.

active solana wallets would be millions of wallets, and performing an airdrop to that many wallets would cost thousands of $
May be check wallets that interacts with a specific program in the last X weeks ?
